# I Run stable diffusion,It`s wrong RuntimeError: "LayerNormKernelImpl" not implemented for 'Half',

Tags: stable-diffusion

I Run stable diffusion,It`s wrong RuntimeError: "LayerNormKernelImpl" not implemented for 'Half',help me,how i do?

I have no idea for it

Answer (score 26):

'LayerNorm' is one of the layers in the Model. Looks like you're trying to load the diffusion model in float16(Half) format on CPU which is not supported. For float16 format, GPU needs to be used. For CPU run the model in float32 format.

Reference: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/52291

Comment: `dtype=torch.float16 ——> dtype=torch.float32`
thankyou for the link

Comment: where exactly, dtype=torch.float16 appears in several archives. It seems more like a viable solution the one above, in wich parameter --half is added to commandline_args = os.environ.get('COMMANDLINE_ARGS', "--skip-torch-cuda-test --no-half") , probably that fixes all.

Answer (score 17):

I solved it in the following way, modify the `launch.py` file in the following way, add the following line of code:

```py
commandline_args = os.environ.get('COMMANDLINE_ARGS', "--skip-torch-cuda-test --no-half")
```

[image: launch.py file and the modified line of code just as stated above]

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure what your environment is. I can show you what I have encountered.
I also encountered this error during my Colab testing, which appeared after I changed my model.
Then I realized that I had forgotten to assign the pipe to CUDA.
After running the code below, everything was fine.

```
pipe = pipe.to("cuda")
```

Comment: Not with a 16xx card, which prefers float32.

Answer (score 8):

Instantiate the pipeline with `float32`, it will run slower but it will run ;)

```
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float32)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Windows System,
Edit *webui-user.bat* file

```
set COMMANDLINE_ARGS= --skip-torch-cuda-test --no-half
```

Comment: SOmeone already answered the same before.

Answer (score 4):

*RuntimeError: “LayerNormKernelImpl” not implemented for ‘Half’*

I have successfully solved this problem by way of

Start the webUI with the following Mac OS Terminal command.

cd stable-diffusion-webui
./webui.sh --precision full --no-half

Special Thank >>
https://stable-diffusion-art.com/install-mac/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of the [A1111 WebUI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) you can add the needed arguments to `webui-user.sh`

```
# Commandline arguments for webui.py, for example: export COMMANDLINE_ARGS="--medvram --opt-split-attention"
export COMMANDLINE_ARGS="--skip-torch-cuda-test --no-half"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, and here is the solution, first do this inside your launch.py:

```
commandline_args = os.environ.get('COMMANDLINE_ARGS', "")
commandline_args = os.environ.get('COMMANDLINE_ARGS', "--skip-torch-cuda-test --no-half")
```

If you have done it already and still not working then you need to run the below command

> ./webui.sh --precision full --no-half